# XSLT 1.0 Grouping on multiple values on multiple levels

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

- edited in response to comments *

Hello,

I am an XSLT noob and need some help.  I am trying to do an filter/group combination with XSLT 1.0 (can't use XSLT 2.0 for this application).

Here is an example of the xml

```
<entry>
  <item>
    <name>Widget 2</name>
    <rank>2</rank>
    <types>
       <type>Wood</type>
       <type>Fixed</type>
       <type>Old</type>
    </types>
  </item>
   <item>
    <name>Widget 1</name>
    <rank>2</rank>
    <types>
       <type>Metal</type>
       <type>Broken</type>
       <type>Old</type>
    </types>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Widget 3</name>
    <rank>1</rank>
    <types>
       <type>Metal</type>
       <type>New</type>
    </types>
  </item>
</entry>
```

Now what I want to do is output html where I get a subset of the XML based on `<type>` and then group on rank.  For example, if the user selects all items with the type Metal, the output should be:

`<p class="nospace"><font color="#800000">`
`<b>Rank 1</b></font></p>`
`<li id="mylist"><b>Widget 3</b></li>`
`<br\>`

`<p class="nospace"><font color="#800000">`
`<b>Rank 2</b></font></p>`
`<li id="mylist"><b>Widget 1</b></li>`
`<br\>`

of if the user user chooses the type Old the output would be

`<p class="nospace"><font color="#800000">`
`<b>Rank 2</b></font></p>`
`<li id="mylist"><b>Widget 1</b></li>`
`<li id="mylist"><b>Widget 2</b></li>`
`<br\>`

I can group using keys on rank along easily enough, but trying to do both is not working.  Here is a sample of the xslt I have tried:

```
<xsl:param name="typeParam"/>
<xsl:key name="byRank" use="rank" match="item"/>

<xsl:for-each select="item[count(.|key('byRank',rank)[1])=1]">
  <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="rank"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="key('byRank',rank)">
    <xsl:sort select="name"/>
    <xsl:if test="count(rank)&gt;0">
      <p class="nospace"><font color="#800000"><b>Rank<xsl:value-of select="rank"/></b></font></p>
      <xsl:for-each select="types[types=$typeParam]">
        <li id="mylist"><b><xsl:value-of select="../name"/></b></li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    <br/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The result I get from this is I do indeed get the subset of my xml that I want but it also displays all of the various rank values. I want to limit it to just the ranks of the type that is specified in $typeParam.

I have tried moving the for-each statement to earlier in the code as well as modifying the if statement to select for $typeParam but neither works. I have also tried concat-ing my key with rank and type but that doesn't seem to work either (It only works if the type in $typeParam is the first child under types).

Thanks

jeff

Comment: This is not so clear to me because the input sample has only one case and because there is no exact desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kItemByRank" match="item" use="rank"/>
    <xsl:param name="pType" select="'Old'"/>
    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <xsl:for-each select="item[count(.|key('kItemByRank',rank)[1])=1]">
            <xsl:sort select="rank" data-type="number"/>
            <xsl:variable name="vGroup" select="key('kItemByRank',rank)[
                                                   types/type = $pType
                                                ]"/>
            <xsl:if test="$vGroup">
                <p class="nospace">
                    <font color="#800000">
                        <b>
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Rank ',rank)"/>
                        </b>
                    </font>
                </p>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$vGroup">
                    <xsl:sort select="name"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
                <br/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <li id="mylist">
            <b>
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </b>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<p class="nospace">
    <font color="#800000">
        <b>Rank 1</b>
    </font>
</p>
<li id="mylist">
    <b>Widget 3</b>
</li>
<br />
<p class="nospace">
    <font color="#800000">
        <b>Rank 2</b>
    </font>
</p>
<li id="mylist">
    <b>Widget 1</b>
</li>
<br />
```

And whit `pType` param set to `'Old'`, output:

```
<p class="nospace">
    <font color="#800000">
        <b>Rank 2</b>
    </font>
</p>
<li id="mylist">
    <b>Widget 1</b>
</li>
<li id="mylist">
    <b>Widget 2</b>
</li>
<br />
```